# asp.net core - create ActionContext with ActionDescriptor s et to ControllerActionDescriptor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Trying to unit test custom `IAsyncAuthorizationFilter`. Need to create `ActionContext` manually with fixture values.

Can't create `ActionContext` with `ActionDescriptor` being `ControllerActionDescriptor`

Version 1 (works):

```
var actionContext1 = new ActionContext(new DefaultHttpContext(), new RouteData(), new ActionDescriptor());
// actionContext1.ActionDescriptor is NOT null
```

Version 2 (doesn't work):

```
var actionContext2 = new ActionContext(new DefaultHttpContext(), new RouteData(), new ControllerActionDescriptor());
// actionContext1.ActionDescriptor is null
```

Not sure why `ActionDescriptor` is `null` when i set `new ControllerActionDescriptor()` to it.

Any ideas ?

Comment: You are creating `actionContext2` but check ActionDecriptor of `actionContext1`?

Comment: actionContext1.ActionDescriptor is NOT null BUT actionContext1.ActionDescriptor is null